# Sending http headers with python

Tags: python, html, sockets, client

I've set up a little script that should feed a client with html.

```
import socket

sock = socket.socket()
sock.bind(('', 8080))
sock.listen(5)
client, adress = sock.accept()


print "Incoming:", adress
print client.recv(1024)
print

client.send("Content-Type: text/html\n\n")
client.send('<html><body></body></html>')

print "Answering ..."
print "Finished."

import os
os.system("pause")
```

But it is shown as plain text in the browser. Can you please tell what I need to do ? I just can't find something in google that helps me..

Thanks.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The response header should include a response code indicating success.
Before the *Content-Type* line, add:

```
client.send('HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\n')
```

Also, to make the test more visible, put some content in the page:

```
client.send('<html><body><h1>Hello World</body></html>')
```

After the response is sent, close the connection with:

```
client.close()
```

and

```
sock.close()
```

As the other posters have noted, terminate each line with `\r\n` instead of `\n`.

Will those additions, I was able to run successful test.  In the browser, I entered `localhost:8080`.

Here's all the code:

```
import socket

sock = socket.socket()
sock.bind(('', 8080))
sock.listen(5)
client, adress = sock.accept()

print "Incoming:", adress
print client.recv(1024)
print

client.send('HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\n')
client.send("Content-Type: text/html\r\n\r\n")
client.send('<html><body><h1>Hello World</body></html>')
client.close()

print "Answering ..."
print "Finished."

sock.close()
```

Comment: ... and don't forget to replace \n\n to \r\n\r\n, since HTTP needs CRLF to be send after headers.

Comment: and better to use '\r\n\r\n' instead of '\n\n'

Comment: Wow, thats it. Thank you ! Are there any related documents about the exchange between server and client with the http protocol ?

Comment: @NiklasR You can start with an overview on wikipedia http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol and then get the details at http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616.html

Comment: @RaymondHettinger,I was wondering how the browser could recognize the end of http response `body` without `Content-Length` in the http response `header`

Comment: @GaryGauh Content-Length is necessary if you leave the connection open.  But if you close the connection as we do above, the browser can interpret "hanging-up the phone" as the "there is no more content coming".

Answer (score 0):

[webob](http://docs.webob.org/en/latest/index.html) does the dirty http details for you as well

```
from webob import Response
....

client.send(str(Response("<html><body></body></html>")))
```

Comment: Note that webob uses `\n` to separate lines instead of the correct `\r\n`. This is [#146](https://github.com/Pylons/webob/pull/146). Browsers don't seem to care, though, so your solution will work fine in most cases.

Answer (score 0):

Python 3 variant of [@Raymond's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/424499/raymond-hettinger) [snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8315292) (suitable for viewing browser's http request headers).

```
import socket

sock = socket.socket()
sock.bind(('', 8080)) # ('127.0.0.1', 8080) for localhost
sock.listen(5)
client, address = sock.accept()

print('Incoming:', address)
print(client.recv(1024))
print()

encoding = 'ascii'
client.send(bytes('HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\n', encoding))
client.send(bytes('Content-Type: text/html\r\n\r\n', encoding))
client.send(bytes('<html><body><h1>Hello World</h1></body></html>', encoding))
client.close()

print('Answering ...')
print('Finished.')

sock.close()
```